# Does loading too many function libraries decrease speed?

Tags: php, function, time, loading, libraries

I have a series of function libraries that I have set to autoload in the CodeIgniter framework. Would auto-loading (i.e. including) many libraries increase the processing time of each page, and would such delay be significant?

I know it can be dependant upon many other factors, but in general, is there such a thing as loading too many libraries?

Comment: Does driving longer distances cost you more gas?

Comment: Nice comparison, but shouldn't it rather be the load of the car than the distance in this case?

Comment: @Wesley Pretty silly and disappointing comment really. Gas usage is directly related to mileage. Linking to function libraries while using only a few functions is hardly the same thing. Also, this focuses on whether any delay incurred is significant or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

depending on the order in which the autoloaders have been registered, a classname might be passed trough multiple autoloaders, which might use a `file_exists`, `strpos` or `preg_match` to see if the classname matches their library.

Having to load 100+ classes a request, this can become a costly thing.

Answer (score 0):

To be short. **Yes**, it will have an impact on page load.

**Yes**, there is a "too-much-libraries". Depending on server configuration. (Max execution memory, if I remember right)